# adjacency list and adjacency matrix are able to logically present a non-linear data structure

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

how adjacency list and adjacency matrix are able to logically present a non-linear data structure, even though they are themselves linear. Someone Pls explain

Comment: Your question doesn't make clear sense. A graph is not the sort of a thing that is linear or nonlinear (what exactly is a "non-linear data structure" in this context?). Matrices can be used in linear algebra, but they can also be used to just store information. Sometimes linear algebra sheds light on the stored information, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I said the same thing to my professor but he still gave this question to me to solve so I thought maybe I was wrong so I posted it here. To clarify my doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacks, queues, lists, vectors/arrays: they all store data linearly in the sense that items are stored one after the other. There is the notion of "item A comes **before** item B", and "item C comes **after** item B". One before, one after. They only differ in how items can be accessed (FIFO, LIFO, by rank, by position).

Trees (a type of graph) store data hierarchically. There's not really a before/after relation. Instead, items are stored based on a parent/child relationship. Then, we can say "the **parent** of item A is B", and "the **children** of item A are B, C, D, and E".

Graphs store any type of relation between elements. An item can be related to any other item, as expressed by an edge. We can say "item A is **related** to B, C, D, E" and "item B is **related** to A and F". It is in this sense that they are nonlinear. An adjacency list and adjacency matrix accomplish this by, effectively, maintaining a (linear) list of these relationships.

Comment: can you share some resources and/or articles that would explain what you wrote in more detail probably with some codes?